# How to get ABI (Application Binary Interface) in android

Tags: android, abi

It may be a duplicated question, but i'm unable to find it.
I wonder how we can get what's the ABI of a phone, using code. I know that there's different Interface that may dictated in gradle file. But the problem is how i can get exactly the ABI of a certain device, so that i can manually copy it to system/lib/ folder using SuperSU.
Thank you.

```
android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
```

Answer (score 37):

There are two ways that you can do this. One is deprecated but still works while the other requires the phone to be running Android 5.0 or greater.

**The Deprecated Way**

If you want to support all current phones you can use:

```
import android.os.Build;
String ABI = Build.CPU_ABI;
```

**The Newer Way**

The newer way actually will provide a list of all supported ABIs, the first index being the most preferred ABI to use ([API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS)):

```
import android.os.Build;
String ABI = Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0];
```

Both ways have been tested to work on Android 5.1.1, they will return one of the following:

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- armeabi-v7a-hard
- arm64-v8a
- x86
- x86_64
- mips
- mips64

Future ABIs should be listed here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa

Answer (score 27):

Look up here:

[image]

not there?

**Through ADB shell:**

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```

**Though Java code:**

```
import android.os.Build;
Log.d("myabi", Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0]);
```

Comment: do you have the source for the screenshot?

Comment: I guess https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis , now it has changed though

Answer (score 7):

**TLDR**: Here is a combined version of bandoncontortion's solution, which works on all Android versions:

```
public String getAbi() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // on newer Android versions, we'll return only the most important Abi version
        return Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0];
    }
    else {
        // on pre-Lollip versions, we got only one Abi
        return Build.CPU_ABI;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the ABI that current process/runtime is running under (e.g. an arm64/x86_64 processor can run a 32-bit app_process to save memory), you should use `CPU_ABI`, `CPU_ABI2` as it will return the correct result.

If you do not want to use deprecated API but is ok with using internal (core platform) APIs, you can also use reflection and access `dalvik.runtime.VMRuntime.getRuntime().is64Bit()` (or `getCurrentInstructionSet`) and filter `SUPPORTED_ABIS` by yourself. See the source code for static constructor of `android.os.Build` for more information.